# after a user enters an input, i put return menu() but menu() doesn't work

Tags: python, function, return

i have this problem:

```
def thing():
    e = input("Are you sure you want to enter this menu?")
    if e == "yes":
        while True:
            placeholder()
    elif e == "no":
        return menu() #<-- THIS
    else:
        print("invalid response")

def menu():
    print("""
what do you want to do?
1. Enter thing
2. Don't enter thing
""")
    ans = input("Enter your response here:\n")
    if ans == "1":
        thing()
    elif ans == "2":
        pass
    else:
        print("invalid response")
```

If `e == no` then it won't go to menu() like i expected but it just stopped and i need a way to make what happens after they input "no" to be `menu()` yet it will not do that. any way to fix?

Comment: You don't show how you run these functions, but it likely has to do with menu() calling thing() calling menu() recursively.  Make a [mcve] that clearly shows what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: man coding is too hard

Comment: It should be recursively calling `menu()` when `e` is `"no"`.  But you shouldn't be doing that.  If you do, you will start stacking up calls that will likely result in unexpected behavior when you try to unwind the call stack.  Instead, it seems like all you really need to do is return from the function, without calling `menu()`, and have the caller handle it.  If necessary, it could return some value that indicates what the caller should do.

Comment: `menu()` doesn't return anything, so returning its value doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If e is "no", then this code will call `menu()`. If this is not happening, the problem must be elsewhere. Please show us the full code, and a sample session that has the printed output and your input.